# how to know all ByteArrayDataSource types that are acceptable?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm writing an API that sends email with attachment and I see that the code:

```java
ByteArrayDataSource imageDataSource = new ByteArrayDataSource(rawImage,"image/png");
```

I want to pass the type of the file, but I can't find all types that ByteArrayDataSource accepts.

Where can I find it? I saw that I can put anything, like "any/thing" that accept it. But, there is no preview or I cant open the file without telling my SO which program to use.

Comment: I'm going to guess and say "Any", since it would read the array/stream/string and simply pass the mimetype on. Don't take my word though - look at the source ;)

Comment: Read https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/util/ByteArrayDataSource.html (assuming this is javax.mail.util.ByteArrayDataSource)

Comment: Looks like I'm right according to https://github.com/javaee/javamail/blob/master/mail/src/main/java/javax/mail/util/ByteArrayDataSource.java. It simply accepts any mimetype you give it

Comment: Hmmm understand now... Its like any MIME type, like from this source: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types

Thanks. I was trying to find some enum or anything like that